# fallback to alternate function when templated function instantiation fails

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

i need to store pointers to instanced template functions and when function cannot be instanced i would like to store pointer to empty function instead. I looked into SFINAE but i dont think it applies here.

```
struct StaticEntity {
    double position;
};

struct DynamicEntity {
    double position;
    double speed;
};

class MoveSystem {
public:
    template <typename T>
    void update(T& entity, double dt) {
        entity.position += entity.speed*dt;
    }
};

typedef void (*updateEntitiesFunc)(void* system, void* entity, double dt);

template <typename S, typename E>
static void update(void* system, void* entity, double dt)
{
    // here if inner function cannot be instanced i would like to skip it and do "nothing" instead
    ((S*)system)->update(*(E*)entity, dt);
}

int main() {
    updateEntitiesFunc uf = update<MoveSystem, DynamicEntity>;
    updateEntitiesFunc uf2 = update<MoveSystem, StaticEntity>;
    //^ this does not compile
    //  gives error: 'struct StaticEntity' has no member named 'speed'
    //  i would like it to compile and contain pointer to empty function
    return 0;
}
```

It probably is solvable with some template magic that i just cant figure out.
Ideally without adding complexity to both Entity and System classes.

**Design motivation:**

for all my entity and system types i want to create a static array of function pointers:

```
updateEntitiesFunc funcs[EntityTypes::getTypesCount()][SystemTypes::getTypesCount()];
```

And then at runtime call correct function with type-ids:

```
funcs[entity->getTypeId()][system->getTypeId()](&system, &entity, dt);
```

At runtime i will check if entity is compatible with system but it is runtime information. So all function pointers must be registered for all entity-system pairs at compile time, even though they are not compatible. This is where i wanted to create those no-op functions.

Comment: What do you mean by *"here if inner function **cannot be instanced** i would like to skip it and do "nothing" instead"*?  You mean, any error whatsoever, or one where the `S::update` method doesn't exist, or one where the `S::update` instance would fail to compile, or what?

Comment: When it exists but does not compile (the case in the code that i posted)

Comment: `MoveSystem::update` requires a member variable called `speed` to exist, there's no way around that. Just give `StaticEntity` a speed that's always set to `0`.

Comment: Can we modify `MoveSystem::update` at all?

Comment: Are you asking for a work-around for a bad design?

Comment: Go ahead, if some simple solution exists, better modifying systems then entities i guess.

Answer (score 4):

First, metaprogramming boilerplate:

```
namespace details {
  template<class...>struct voider{using type=void;};
  template<class...Ts>using void_t=typename voider<Ts...>::type;

  template<template<class...>class Z, class, class...Ts>
  struct can_apply:
    std::false_type
  {};
  template<template<class...>class Z, class...Ts>
  struct can_apply<Z, void_t<Z<Ts...>>, Ts...>:
    std::true_type
  {};
}
template<template<class...>class Z, class...Ts>
using can_apply=details::can_apply<Z,void,Ts...>;
```

Now, we can detect properties:

```
template<class T>
using speed_t = decltype(std::declval<T>().speed);
template<class T>
using position_t = decltype(std::declval<T>().position);

template<class T>
using has_speed = can_apply<speed_t, T>;
template<class T>
using has_position = can_apply<position_t, T>;

template<class S, class E>
using update_call_t = decltype( std::declval<S>().update( std::declval<E>(), 0.0 ) );

template<class S, class E>
using has_update = can_apply< update_call_t, S, E >;
```

and we have three traits, `has_position`, `has_update` and `has_speed` that are useful.

Now we fix `MoveSystem`:

```
struct MoveSystem {
  template <class T>
  std::enable_if_t< has_speed<T&>{} && has_position<T&>{} >
  update(T& entity, double dt) {
    entity.position += entity.speed*dt;
  }
};
```

next, we modify update:

```
namespace updates {
  template<class S, class E>
  std::enable_if_t< has_update<S,E>{} >
  update(S* system, E* entity, double dt ) {
    system->update(*entity, dt);
  }
  void update(void*, void*, double) {}
}
template<class S, class E>
void update(void* system, void* entity, double dt) {
  using updates::update;
  update(static_cast<S*>(system), static_cast<E*>(entity), dt );
}
```

to check for the `.update` method working with those parameters.

I ADL-enabled the code such that if the class has a `friend void update( S*, E*, double )` it will also work.

This is all SFINAE work.  Note that adding more properties once we have `can_apply` is pretty easy.  Make an alias that generates a type that only works if the property is satisfied, then write a `can_apply` alias that converts that application to a compile-time boolean test.

As an aside, MSVC2015 is not a C++11 compiler, in that it cannot compile the above code.  In MSVC you have to track down some proprietary extensions to do the equivalent of the above code.  This involves writing `has_position` and the other traits differently.  They call the failure to obey the C++11 standard in this case an inability to do "expression SFINAE".

Note that the above uses a handful of C++14 features.  Replace `std::enable_if_t<??>` with `typename std::enable_if<??>::type`, replace `has_position<??>{}` with `has_position<??>::value` and similar other changes if your compiler doesn't support it.